# Google spreadsheets fixed width for embedding in a google site

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites, fixed-width

Really hoping someone can answer this question as it seems pretty straight forward;

I have a google site and I'm inserting a google spreadsheet into the layout (header, left-hand nav, one column content area which is where the spreadsheet is going). Sadly, this creates a horizontal scroll in the area specified for the google spreadsheet. How do I (or can I) set the width of my google spreadsheet so that it automatically resizes to the width of the area in my google site specified for the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

If the gadget doesnt allow it, you can edit the page html to set the iframe width to 100%, as in:
`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false" style="height: 28em; width: 100%;"></iframe>`

note this is for a published url but it should work with any iframe embed. Take a look at [an example here](http://plusfortrello.blogspot.com/2015/04/donations.html) thou its on a blogger page.